# Convert PDF files to Text in PHP using pdftotext does not produce clean output

Tags: php, linux, pdf

I tried every program and script I could find to convert pdf files to text.  Finally I thought I would try xpdf's pdftotext. First, it is incredibly easy to get pdftotext working. You just copy the binary to the linux server and run it.  You do not have to install it or have any system permissions.  Then from PHP I did the following.

```
$command = "<file location>/pdftotext   $file_pdf $file_text";
exec($command);
```

I had to run "pwd" and specify the full path name for  but that worked.

To clean it up I am doing the following;

```
$text = file_get_contents ($file_text);
$text = preg_replace('/[^ ]{14}[^ ]*/', '', $text);
$text = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/', "", $text);
$text = wordwrap($text);
echo $text;
```

There are a lot of options on pdftotext but I could not find any that would remove the garbage for me.  There are lots of examples.
Ç«G"!Gmc?nTé+ä^LÉ|3:}BïL0aû7ÃE+¨Úè0óÚ/Ä;7ù3£\ðë»êãc M¹ÜC°ér¥,E¤Ûc×<ãÜÍ_^L½ç

Some are text like CDFDCFDGVCVFDDDFDDFCCCDSCCSE&GG and on and on for sometimes hundreds of characters without a space.

Is there a better way to clean up the output of a pdftotext file?

Comment: Can you copy sensible text from this PDF using Acrobat Pro? If not, then the data required to convert from the private encoding used in this file to "plain text" is missing. If so, you need to manually find out which code represents what character, and do the translation yourself.

Comment: I tried Acrobat Pro and you are correct.  I am getting the same results so I guess I am doing as good a job as can be done with the input file I have.  My filters take out most of the bad stuff so I guess that is it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pdf's in question have text.  The best solution I found was close to what I had.  I want to document if for anyone who finds this and has a similar problem.  The solution presented by James Madison would be great if I had images and wanted to pull the text from them so +1 for his solution although I did not try it.

What I did was create a file using this line

```
$command = "/<my location>/pdftotext -layout  $file_pdf $file_text";
exec($command);
```

And filter it with this code

```
$text = file_get_contents ($file_text);
$text = preg_replace('/[^ ]{14}[^ ]*/', '', $text);
$text = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/', "", $text);
$text = preg_replace('/\n[\s]*/',"\n",$text); // remove all leading blanks]
$text = wordwrap($text,150);
$text = str_replace("\n", "\n<br>", $text);
$text = preg_replace('/<br>..?.?\n/',"",$text);// remove lines with 1,2, or 3 characters
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Tesseract!  Works at the Linux prompt as an executable.  Any language that can call out to the OS can simply do so to invoke it. PHP can do this.  To install Tesseract, you need Leptonica, and Leptonica in turn needs various libraries.  The dependency hell that I went through I baked into this code, which, if you substitute file names for latest versions (this code worked as-is as of 10-Jan-2014), it should all work fine.  You do need GCC to build and probably root/sudo here and there:

```
# Home page: https://code.google.com/p/leptonica/
# Download page: http://www.leptonica.com/download.html
yum install libpng-devel
yum install libtiff-devel
wget http://www.leptonica.com/source/leptonica-1.69.tar.gz
tar xzf leptonica-1.69.tar.gz
./configure
make
make install
export LIBLEPT_HEADERSDIR=/usr/local/include # Add to .profile.

# Home page: http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/
yum install libtool
tar xzf tesseract-3.02.tar.gz # Makes tesseract-ocr directory, no version.
tar xzf tesseract-3.02.eng.tar.gz # Makes tesseract-ocr/tessdata directory.
cd tesseract-ocr
./autogen.sh
./configure --with-extra-libraries=/usr/local/lib
make
make install
export TESSDATA_PREFIX=/export/home/xxxxxx/build/tesseract-ocr # Add to .profile.
tesseract –v # Output will verify also that Leptonica is installed correctly.
```

I've had spectacular results with the solution.

Comment: What does it do?  Does it create an image of the PDF and do OCR on the image?  Or does it extract the text like pdftotext?

Comment: Ah, good point.  It OCR's.  Not just extract text.  If you just want text out of a PDF, consider: http://pdfbox.apache.org/, which I've also had great success with.  PDF box even does slick things like understand table structures and page boundries that have footers and such.

Comment: Have you compared PDFbox to pdftotext from XPDF?

Comment: I've never worked with pdftotext.  Thanks for the pointer.  If PDF box doesn't ever meet a need I will.